# 404 Using UI-Bootstrap and Plunker

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, plunker

I have the following in my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fZZuzqVGCz8UXlyVkyg7?p=preview)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui/0.4.0/angular-ui.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.22/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.22"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
  <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui/0.4.0/angular-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.10.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.10.0/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
  <accordion close-others="false">
    <accordion-group heading="Company" ng-click="toggleOpen()">
      <div class="row" data-ng-repeat="item in companyValues">
        <div class="col-xs-6">

          <input name="companyFilter" type="radio" value="{{item.value}}" id="{{item.name}}-filter-radio" ng-model="userData.companyFilter" ng-change="saveUserPreferences()" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 pull-text-left">{{item.name}}</div>
    </accordion-group>
  </accordion>
</body>

</html>
```

However, when I try to run I get a 404 on template/accordion/accordion-group.html. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your markup loads two different versions of `ui.bootstrap`.

1. A version with templates for components pre-loaded in Angular.js' `$templateCache` service.
2. A version with no pre-loaded templates for if you want to tweak control looks.

Since version #2 is loaded 2nd, it appears that all the pre-loaded templates are not available.

**Solution**: Delete the line:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.10.0/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/JyNu2hggAFt33hTvfoXo?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

When you use angular.ui you also have to include angular.ui.tpls in your dependencies like so:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ui.bootstrap.tpls']);
```